# MySqlDataAdapter Appears to be Missing from .Net Core

Tags: mysql, macos, powershell, .net-core, powershell-core

I have an old powershell script that I am porting over from Windows to .Net Core running on OS X. The script connects to a MySQL DB and reads / writes data.

When I ran it under Windows I was able to use the MySqlDataAdapter to store the data. However, this does not appear to be possible using the new official MySQL DB provider (here is the link to the provider: [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/mysql/index.html) ). Powershell is version v6.0.0-alpha.12

Here is a cut down example of the code:

```
$command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($query, $connection)
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)
$dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

Try {
    $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
    $dataTable = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
    $dataTable = $dataSet.Tables[0]
    $connection.Close()
} Catch [exception] {
    $dataAdapter.Dispose()
    $command.Dispose()
    $dataAdapter = $null
    return $Error 
}
```

The error it returns is:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Does anyone know of an alternative/better way to store data for offline use? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: `MySqlAdapter` cannot be present for .NET Core 1 since there are no `DataTable` there. For .NET Core 2, it seems nobody has bothered add support yet (see: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,657477,658168#msg-658168)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest version of MySql.Data being delivered as a NuGet package: [MySql.Data 7.0.6-IR31](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/7.0.6-IR31).

The description states that it supports .NETStandard 1.6, hence it should be able to be utilized in .NET Core.

Comment: -I just tried that package it still didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since dotnetcore2.0 is out with ADO support it is possible to get mysql to compile and work. I became tired of waiting to Oracle to do a release or even a beta/alpha so I took matters into my own hands and took a look at the code and the situation. In about 2 or 3 hours of fiddling with code, reading api and a little bit of pure dumb luck, I was able to compile mysql 8.0.3 against netcore2.0. I simply had to manually change the project file to netcore 2.0 and modify the compiler directives. In the end I did not have to add even 1 line of code. Although I had to remove many lines and copy a few files. The end result is mysql 8.0.3 compiled with mysqldataadapter and the command builder. I have already tested it with some of my apps and fill seems to work fine at least in Windows/ I have only ported a few small programs I did that use the connection builder and a dataadapter with fill no updates,inserts or deletes to the dataset.

My version is still largely untested and most defnitly a work in progress. I hope this encourages someone else to try modifying it. If not I may post my source on github after I am sure its working well enough for basic testing/use until Oracle solves their rectal-cranial inversion and is able to do a proper release.

But it most definitely is possible if your willing to compile it yourself.

UPDATE:
Here is my working code:
https://github.com/amjtech/MySQL.Data